# Agrupar data.frame en R según los registros entre deciles

Tags: r

¿Cómo podría agrupar los registros de un `data.frame` por los intervalos entre deciles?

Sólo se me ocurre:

1. Calcular los deciles (quantile())
2. Crear un df para cada intervalo filtrando los registros entre deciles (filter()).
3. Resumir cada df (summarize())
4. Crear un nuevo df con los resúmenes (rbind())

¿Hay alguna forma más directa de realizar las operaciones?

Gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar `ntile()`, de `dplyr`. Es similar a `quantile()`, pero la sintaxis es más simple: tienes que indicar el vector sobre el que se calculan los ntiles y el número de ntiles. Para deciles sería 10. Eso lo pones en una columna usando `mutate()` y ya tienes la columna clave para armar los grupos con `group_by()`. Después cualquier sumario de cualquier columna se hará por deciles.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  mutate(decil = ntile(wt, n = 10)) %>% #deciles de la variable wt (peso)
  group_by(decil) %>%                   #agrupar aprovechando la variable que acabo de crear
  summarise(media = mean(disp))         #media de desplazamiento por decil de peso
```

¿esto es lo que buscas?